# PHP request on self

Tags: php, apache, file-get-contents, wkhtmltopdf, mod-fastcgi

I experience problem with PHP request on self. In example I will use `file_get_contents()` but same happen for `exec('wkhtmltopdf [*SELF*]')` or `curl()`

- lets name my server example.com
- apache2 installed
- FastCGI (multiple PHP versions 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 7.0)
- now I have 2 dummy scripts

1st script

```
//get-html.php  
file_get_contents('http://example.org/index.html')
```

2nd script

```
//get-php.php
file_get_contents('http://example.org/index.php')
```

Testing
1) command-line: `php get-html.php` // Success
2) browser: `example.org/get-html.php` // Success

1) command-line: `php get-php.php` // Success
2) browser: `example.org/get-php.php` // **Timeout**

What I tried next

- create subdomain like `subdomain.example.org/index.php` to have differet PHP version for `get-php.php` and for `index.php`
- amend /etc/hosts
- request on other sites (like google.com) // Success
- session_write_close() before file_get_contents() and session_start() right after does not work also

So my suspect is mod_fastcgi. It seems like the apache is not able to run 2 instances of this to handle PHP requests which comes from itself. As running script from command line works as expected.

Does anybody have any advice?

Comment: Are the dummy scripts complete? You don't use sessions (they might block as well)

Comment: Good point Mark. Forgot to mention. I have also tried session_write_close(); file_get_contents('http://example.org/index.php'); session_start(); But that was not successful as well. Updating 'What I tried next' section now.

Comment: Please don't start session (or use it at all) for now and try again, that would answer our question if the problem is caused by blocking session or something else.

Comment: `session_write_close(); file_get_contents('example.org/index.php');` same result  though :-( thanks for ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not set PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN what is in default 1.
When I called in PHP script another PHP script from my server over apache it failed as it was not able to create another PHP FCGI instance.

[image: Proper settings of PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN]